# Get region_id From State Abbreviation - Magento 1.4.2

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

How can I programmatically get the region_id in Magento from a 2-character state abbreviation?  I'm using Magento 1.4.2 if that matters at all.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$regionModel = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->loadByCode($regionCode, $countryCode);
$regionId = $regionModel->getId();
```

Comment: And you can always loadByName if you need to! Name being like 'Texas'.

Answer (score 1):

Get the collection of all the states/regions related to specific country.

```
/**
 * Get region collection
 * @param string $countryCode
 * @return array
 */
public function getRegionCollection($countryCode)
{
    $regionCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/region_api')->items($countryCode);
    return $regionCollection;
}
```

Populate region list with region collection. Country code (e.g. NL, NP, EN) is passed as parameter to getRegionCollection function.

```
$regionCollection = $this->getRegionCollection($countryCode);

<select name='customer[region]' id='customer:region' class="validate-select" >
    <option>Please select region, state or province</option>
    <?php
        foreach($regionCollection as $region) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $region['name'] ?>" ><?php echo $region['name'] ?></option>
            <?php
        }
    ?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me.

```
<div class="field">
                    <label for="region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select id="region_id" name="region_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select">
                            <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
                        <?php                        
                        $regions = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('US')->getRegions();
                        foreach($regions as $region)
                        {
                            echo "<option value=$region[name]>".$region['name'] . "</option>";
                        }
                        ?>

                    </select>                       

                    </div>
                </div>
```